# replace json result with form in ajax mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

my view is the same as this

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 ">
     @{Html.RenderAction("Subscribe", "Home");}
  </div>
```

on other hand my action is

```
public ActionResult Subscribe()
    {
        return PartialView("_Subscribe");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(Subscribe subscribe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            subscribe.Active = false;
            subscribe.IpAddress = Request.UserHostName;
            Guid gui = Guid.NewGuid();
            subscribe.ActiveCode = gui;
            subscribe.SubmitDate = DateTime.Now;
            //_db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("subscribe is complate, please check your email", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

in partialview is

```
@model Jar.Models.Subscribe
            <div Id="subForm" class="single-widget">
                @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
                @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "email" } })

            <button type = "submit" id = "btn_Subscribe" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i></button>
}
```

and in ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#btn_Subscribe").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Subscribe")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { Email: $("#Email").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

ok i want when click on subscribe button email send to database and return json and replace json with all subscribe form(textbox and button ),
now when i click on subscribe, email registered, but return to new page with simple text  "subscribe is complate, please check your email"
how can i change this code to replace subscribe form with json text ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd suggest hooking your event to the `submit` method of the `form` element.

Secondly you should change your response type to an object so that it can be encoded to JSON more effectively, and the response is more consistent:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Subscribe(Subscribe subscribe)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // your code...
        return Json(new { Message = "subscribe is complate, please check your email" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new { Message = "error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Lastly, to achieve your goal you can use the `text()` method to see the content of the `div` containing the form, which will replace the content. Try this:

```
$("#subForm form").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Subscribe")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {  
      Email: $("#Email").val() 
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#subForm').text(data.Message); // note the use of text() here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i use it but when i click on button page refresh and show source page code

Comment: Sorry! My mistake - I forgot to add the `preventDefault()` call to the event